# boost last_write_time first chance exception raised. Why?

Tags: c++, exception, boost, boost-filesystem

I'm writing app that does some hot-reloading of files and from time to time, "First chance exception" is raised by debugger. I've tried several tests and I cannot figure out why this keep happening.

```
time_t time = fs::last_write_time("filename.xxx"); // fs = boost::filesystem
```

when I print `time` to console, all the time I get relatively normal values, like `1435695997`, which make sense. When exception is raised, I have to dig into Locals and it has negative value instead, like `-3689348814741910324`. To me this look like non-initialized value of variable.

I've wrapped this into `try` and `catch`, but in my book, this is not really solution.
 Does anybody stumbled into anything like this?

Comment: The relevant code is missing. On a whim, I'll predict [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Anything can happen. Since you mention "hot reloading" are you by any chance mutating state shared by multiple threads without proper exclusive locking?

Comment: I have really not figure out reason why this keeps happening, although my solution was to check if value > 0. This is not optimal, but since I'm checking constantly for new changes in file  it's working fine.

Comment: The relevant code is still missing. On what platforms does the issue arise? It might be a bug in Boost but we can't tell without information

Comment: -3689348814741910324 = 0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC which means [you've accessed uninitialized memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)